# CAShapeLayer Not Updating in Animation

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation

I have got a CAShapeLayer containing a basic shape, which is created during the 'drawRect' method, which can be seen below.

```
override func drawRect(frame: CGRect)
    {
        let rectangleRect = CGRectMake(frame.minX + 2.5, frame.minY + 2.5, frame.width - 5, frame.height - 5)
        let rectanglePath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rectangleRect, cornerRadius: 4)
        shapeLayer.path = rectanglePath.CGPath

        if (self.active == true)
        {
            shapeLayer.fillColor = selectedColor.CGColor
        } else
        {
            shapeLayer.fillColor = buttonColor.CGColor
        }

        shapeLayer.strokeColor = buttonOutlineColor.CGColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 5.0

        self.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)

    }
```

I use this to create a simple square, with a stroke. I then have another method, which has an animation for the `CAShapeLayer`. However, when the method is called, nothing is changed on the `CAShapeLayer`. The animation method is show below.

```
let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeColor")
    animation.duration = 0.5
    animation.repeatCount = 10
    animation.fromValue = UIColor.whiteColor()
    animation.toValue = UIColor.redColor()
    animation.autoreverses = true
    shapeLayer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "strokeColor")
```

The variable `shapeLayer` has been defined at the top of the Class. I am very interested in why this does not work. Any advice on how to fix this will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an issue that plagues me every time I use Quartz/CoreGraphics. The fromValue and toValue need `CGColor` parameters, and not `UIColor`.

Just change it so that they're `UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor` and `UIColor.redColor().CGColor`

In general, if you're using the prefix `CA` or `CG`, you're going to want to use `CGColor` *et al*.

Comment: Such a simple thing, didn't even think of that. Thanks!